# vector - swap two elements when elements have const members

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, constants, swap

I have the following code

```
class a {
public:
    const int aa;
    a(int aa) : aa(aa){}
};
int main() {
    std::vector<a> v;
    v.emplace_back(1);
    v.emplace_back(2);
    v.emplace_back(3);
    v.emplace_back(4);

    std::iter_swap(v.begin() + 1, v.rbegin());

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error when I try to swap two elements of the vector.

```
Error   C2280   'a &a::operator =(const a &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

I understand it's because `a` has a constant member, but I am not able to figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: You simply can't.

Comment: Hmmm, I can see where he is coming from. He wants to swap the objects not manipulate them. But yeah that is not intended in c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580635/how-to-copy-or-swap-objects-of-a-type-that-contains-members-that-are-reference) thread following works:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    const int value;
    Foo(const int &&from) : value(std::move(from)){}
    Foo(const Foo &&other) : value(std::move(other.value)){}
    Foo & operator=(Foo && source) {
        this -> ~ Foo ();
        new (this) Foo(std::move(source));
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> v;
    v.emplace_back(1);
    v.emplace_back(2);
    v.emplace_back(3);
    v.emplace_back(4);

    std::cout << (v.begin() + 1)->value << "," <<v.rbegin()->value << std::endl;
    std::iter_swap(v.begin() + 1, v.rbegin());
    std::cout << (v.begin() + 1)->value << "," <<v.rbegin()->value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `Foo` is inherited from, or if any of the destroy/create operations could throw, this is not recoverable from...

Comment: I'm not saying it is a solution, just one more option to discution.

Comment: I'm just saying it is an insane solution.  I cannot think why it isn't always illegal, so it is *a* solution.

Comment: This not terrible at all. Foo cannot be inherited from since Foo is constructed inplace in the vector and placement new just calls the constructor, so if the constructor does not throw, the placement new will never throw. (normal new does a memory allocation that can fail)

Comment: Took me a while to understand, but I figured it out. It was especially interesting to learn about placement new. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the `swap` changes the value of existing element. Since the elements are const, they cannot be changed hence the compiler error.

If you insist on const elements, your vector should be `vector<a*>` or event better `vector<unique_ptr<a>>`. This will allow you to swap elements without mutating the actual elements of `a`

Comment: I understand now why I can't do what I was trying to do. My new question is why can't I destruct `a` at `v[2]` and move/copy `v[3]` to that position?

Comment: One question at a time

Comment: Should I make a new question? Is it worth asking?

Comment: j2ko gives exactly this answer and it does work. std::swap invokes the copy operator so it will do whatever is programed. The default is an element by element copy.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Since `std::iter_swap` for `std::vector` iterators implementation looks like this:

```
using std::swap;
swap(*iter1, *iter2);
```

you can define your own `swap` function:

```
class A {
    const int aa;
public:
    A(int aa) : aa(aa){}

    void swap(A &other)
    {
        std::swap(const_cast<int &>(aa), const_cast<int &>(other.aa));
    }
};

void inline swap(A &a1, A &a2)
{
    a1.swap(a2);
}
```

And it [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a40e0b1a09df48be)!

For more information about how this works see, for example, famous Scott Meyers book "Effective C++", rule 25. If you can't find, I can try to explain it (mr. Meyers does it better, I think).

@doron's tip about vector of pointers is a really good alternative when objects are large.

### EDIT

@Yakk suggests that to cast a const variable to the non-const one is to cause undefined behaviour. **It is better not to use this way.**

Comment: Casting const away from something originally declared const is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Yakk In general case you are right. Shall edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It also works without r-value and std::move

```
const a& operator=(const a &other)
{
    this->~a();
    new (this) a(other.aa);
    return *this;
}
```